# android studio doesn't open after change studio.vmoptions on ubuntu

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu

I change ***studio.vmoptions*** for speedup but after that my Android Studio doesn't open and when try from terminal I saw this Error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class #

What shoud I do?

Comment: Without knowing *what* exactly you changed, you could revert your "speedup" changes by deleting your old `studio.vmoptions` and replacing it with a new, fresh, unchanged one from the internet. Or better: take your backup of that file, if you have one. If you still want to change, go step by step, make sure to backup.